# Attribute overridding in recipe not working

Tags: chef-infra

Below is a distilled toy-example of my problem, with an error output (the error is irrelevant—the stale values that produced the error is the problem).

I'm simply trying to override a variable.  Then I subscribe to this `ruby_block` and create a file based on the string content of the overridden variable.

```
ruby_block "Get and set volume id" do
    block do
    node.force_override['ec2-consistent-snapshot']['script']['volumes-test'] = 'wtf?'
    end
    action :run
end

file "/var/log/ec2-test" do
    content node['ec2-consistent-snapshot']['script']['volumes-test']
    owner "ec2-user"
    group "ec2-user"
    mode "0666"
    subscribes :create, "ruby_block[Get and set volume id]", :delayed
end
```

[image: showing-failure]

As you can see, the `force_override` is not working.  I've gone through a ton of iterations with different node scopes, using/not using notifies/subscribes, creating new attributes, etc.  My results are seemingly random (I know this isn't the case, but I'm uncertain about what's happening here): sometimes things work fine, sometimes I get stale results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  For reference, I cannot pass the parameter in via json to chef-client (specs require me not to do that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out https://coderanger.net/two-pass/ for an overview of Chef's loading process. The issue here is that resource bodies are evaluated at compile time, but you are setting the new value at converge time.

Comment: I think I understand the article, but how do I go about resolving this issue?

Comment: The simplest solution is probably to delay evaluation: `content lazy { node['ec2-consistent-snapshot']['script']['volumes-test'] }`

Comment: However as you removed all relevant details, I can't actually comment on your real problem. This is why you should be specific in your question but illustrate your actual use case.

Comment: Can't put more details in :( I ended up just setting an environmental variable, but looks like that would have worked too.

Comment: If your employer doesn't allow you to share details of your code, you should inform them they need to purchase support from someone that would be under NDA or hire those people directly. If they don't want to share even that much, you don't get free help, period. Not your call I'm sure, but you should make sure they understand you are likely not getting the resources to do your job.

Comment: Can't was the wrong word.  This wasn't an employer issue.  The rest of the code contains stuff that I just would not want online.  I could have gone through the process of masking all of it, but that wasn't necessary as you had already answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a node attribute inside of a `ruby_block` is horrible code smell.  You really need to be asking why you're doing that and refactor somewhere much earlier.  Ideally you wouldn't be setting any attributes in your recipe code and would be only setting attributes in attributes files.  You may want to rethink if you even want to use an attribute.  They are exceedingly poor tools sometimes and you may want to use the `node[:run_state]` hash, use plain old ruby variables, or use plain ruby objects in libraries.  Changing from writing attribute-driven recipe code to property-driven resource code may also help you out a lot.